# .htaccess regex: cut url after 2nd subdirectory of any url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to cut the url after the 2nd subdirectory - if there is any - of any url, for example:

```
/tag/2nd/3rd/4th/ --> /tag/2nd/

/tag/2nd/3rd/ --> /tag/2nd/

/tag/ --> /tag/
```

Is it possible? I've tried it with

```
^/tag/([^/]*) --> /tag/$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing leading slash your attempt will cause **infinite looping** since `^tag/([^/]*)` will match even `/tag/2nd/` URI.

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(tag/[^/]+)/.+$ /$1/ [L,NC,R=302]
```